# "Select / Unselect" multiple select fields

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple select fields defined in a table column,

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>THIS IS THE PLACE TO SELECT THE PROJECTS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="select_project">
      <select class="projects" id="projects" multiple="multiple" name="projects[]" size="10">
       <option value="1">Project 1</option> 
       <option value="2" selected="selected">project 2</option> 
       <option value="3">Project 3</option>
     </select>
   CLICK HERE SHOULD "UNSELECT"
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to have the feature that when user click on the space of the column besides the selection field, all selected options should back to unselected status, I have used the following jquery to implement,

```
$("#select_project").bind('click', function(){
    $('#projects option').attr('selected', false);
    return false;
});
```

It works but it also affect the selection field, that's when user select a option, it immediately change back to unselected status automatically, how to get rid of this?

Comment: p.s. "deselect" is way cooler than "unselect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course it will clear the selected value immediately after the user has selected something from the drop down list.

You've placed the `<select>` inside the area that is affected by the `.click()` function.  So whenever the user *clicks* on the drop down list to choose something, your function is run - and the selection is cleared.

You have to change the UI so that the place to click to clear the selection is somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

Well yeah, you binded event to the whole table cell, where select box and text are, so it affects both of them. Fixed code:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>THIS IS THE PLACE TO SELECT THE PROJECTS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="select_project">
      <select class="projects" id="projects" multiple="multiple" name="projects[]" size="10">
       <option value="1">Project 1</option> 
       <option value="2" selected="selected">project 2</option> 
       <option value="3">Project 3</option>
     </select>
   <a href="#" id="unselect">CLICK HERE SHOULD "UNSELECT"</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

$("#unselect").bind('click', function(){
    $('#projects option:selected').removeAttr("selected");;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: this is not xhtml-valid ... for selected-state `selected="selected"` and for unselected-state remove the attribute!

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 you need to have write following in order to make unselect two other selectboxes names edit-tid-3 and edit-tid-4 when you click on first select box ( edit-tid-2)

```
jQuery("#edit-tid-2").bind('click', function(){
                jQuery('#edit-tid-3 option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
                        jQuery('#edit-tid-4 option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
                        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be kinda different, relying only on select clicks, without having to add a new button/link to uncheck, if nobody cares about adding a `sel_val` attribute to `<select></select>`, all of course in the `$(function(){ //HERE });` :

```
$('select[multiple=multiple]').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var selectedOpts = $("option:selected",$this);
    if(selectedOpts.length == 1){
        selectedOpts.each(function(){
            if($this.attr('sel_val') == $(this).val()){ // if clicking 2nd time on this
                selectedOpts.removeAttr('selected');
                $this.removeAttr('sel_val');
                $this.trigger('blur');
            }else // if clicking for the first time
               $this.attr('sel_val',$(this).val());
        });
    }

});

$('select[multiple=multiple]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var selectedOpts = $("option:selected",$this);
    if(selectedOpts.length == 1){ // if one item selected only, make it unselectable
        selectedOpts.each(function(){
            $this.attr('sel_val',$(this).val());
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem without creating side effects is use bellow code.

```
$("select[multiple] option")
 .attr({"d_sel":false,"selected":false})
 .mouseover(function(){this.d_sel=this.selected;})
 .click(function(){this.d_sel=(this.selected=(!this.d_sel));});
```